# how to solve Large amount of MAE & MSE?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have designed a model for 1163 samples of 11 features in 1002 time steps. Since it is important to have the effect of each time step on the final output I used LSTM. The problem that I have is that even with different numbers of layers, neurons, and epochs my loss, meaning "MSE"&"MAE" is noticeably high. In the sense that I can say that it is underfitting. Also, I have changed my optimizer parameters but still, the problem exists. The model that I have used is below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

conv1d = Conv1D(input_shape=(None, 16), kernel_size=2, filters=2)    

model = Sequential()
#model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,strides = 1,activation='tanh'))
#model.add(conv1d)    


model.add(layers.LSTM(128,activation='relu' ,input_shape = (1163,10),return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Dense(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))


model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001,epsilon=1e-07)
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mae','mse'])
```

By adding a convolutional layer, is it possible to decrease them or not? If so, how to add a convolutional layer for a regression model with one target(Label) and 10 features.?

Comment: I would use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy loss instead. Or normalize output

Comment: You mean, instead of using MSE or MAE using another loss function? but the problem is that the task is regression. is it ok with also?

Comment: Sorry - missed that your output shape is 1

Comment: Typically with a regression task one would use a sigmoid activation at the last layer and a binary_crossentrophy loss. But the first thing that seems off to me about your model is that I would expect and input_shape of (1002 time steps, 11 features). One would then train the model with mini batches of say 32 samples.

Comment: @PedroMarques I thought that when I have a list of 1163 samples, in each time step, all of the samples should be read in one epoch. Another thing, could you please provide me with an example to show how to train with mini batches?

Comment: Consider editing your question to make it clear what a single example looks like, what the labels look like and if the dataset is public provide a pointer to it. Otherwise synthetic / annonymized data may help better describe the problem.